# Is there a way to redirect nohup output to a log file other than nohup.out?

Tags: io-redirection, nohup

I frequently use the program `nohup` so that my processes are immune to hangups.  So if I want to make the program `program` immune to hangups, I use the command

```
nohup program &
```

where `&` puts the process in the background.

When starting, `nohup` gives me the message:

> nohup: appending output to `nohup.out'

Is there any way to send the output to a file other than `nohup.out`?  Often I want to run many processes in the same directory using `nohup`, but if I do this, all the output gets lumped together in a single `nohup.out` file.

The manual page (for example, [here](http://cims.nyu.edu/cgi-comment/man.cgi?section=1&topic=nohup)) does not seem to have an option for specifying the log file.  Can you please confirm this?  Also, do you have any thoughts of how I can work around this problem?

Comment: A year late, but a good comprehensive answer was given here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4549489/can-i-change-the-name-of-nohup-out

Comment: did you try `nohup python file.py my_ouput.out &`?

Comment: can someone give an explanation of the command? can you explain what the hieroglyphics `2>&1` mean and why it works?

Comment: @CharlieParker `2>&1` redirects `stderr` to `stdout` so when you use `nohup myprogram > myprogram.out 2>&1` both `stdout` and `stderr` will be redirected to `myprogram.out`

Answer (score 206, accepted):

GNU coreutils `nohup` man page indicates that you can use normal redirection:

> If standard input is a terminal, redirect it from `/dev/null`. If standard output is a terminal, append output to `nohup.out` if possible, `$HOME/nohup.out` otherwise. If standard error is a terminal, redirect it to standard output. To save output to FILE, use `nohup COMMAND > FILE`.

Edit: I didn't read your link at first; you may have a different version of `nohup`, although this section suggests that you can still use normal redirection:

```
 nohup.out          The output file of the nohup execution if
                    standard  output is a terminal and if the
                    current directory is writable.
```

You can redirect standard output and standard error to different files:

```
nohup myprogram > myprogram.out 2> myprogram.err &
```

or to the same file:

```
nohup myprogram > myprogram.out 2>&1 &
```

(don't forget the & at the end to put into the background)

Comment: And this isn't specific to GNU utilities, the behavior is specified by POSIX.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. It redirect the output of nohup command rather the output of myprogram.

Comment: @Kris Redirection should take place before the trailing `&` character

Comment: does this also re-direct stderr? I want to direct everything, whether it is an error or output to a single source.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `nohup myprogram > myprogram.out 2>&1 &` ? where adding `&` at the end

Comment: How to ALSO output to command line?

Comment: can you explain what the hieroglyphics `2>&1 ` mean and why it works?

Answer (score 35):

Adding [Jim](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/21804/jim-paris) comment as an answer here for more visibility.

> use `nohup program > program.out &` to write the output to `program.out` instead of `nohup.out`

Comment: does this also re-direct stderr? I want to direct everything, whether it is an error or output to a single source.

Comment: As described in the accepted answer, it needs to be `nohup program > program.out 2>&1 &` to also redirect stderr.

Comment: @ncoghlan can someone give an explanation of the command? can you explain what the hieroglyphics `2>&1` mean and why it works?

Comment: @CharlieParker The four characters `2>&1` tells your shell that any output that **usually** would go to "file handle 2" (stderr) should be redirected to "file handle 1" (stdout).

Comment: @CharlieParker The opposite also works. **Example** `>&2 echo "Error!"` would redirect the output of `echo` to **stderr** instead of **stdout**

Answer (score 15):

Ok, if you are using python and have been searching for a long time, and couldn't get it working. Here you go:

`nohup python -u my_script.py > program.out 2>&1 &`

Reason: python buffers before writing to the output, `-u` disables that behavior.

Update: you can also set env. var. `PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1`  for the same behavior.

Comment: @ncoghlan can someone give an explanation of the command? can you explain what the hieroglyphics `2>&1` mean and why it works?

Comment: @CharlieParker those explanations are all over this page and not very closely related to nohup. It tells error output (notices about the operation of the program) to go to the same place standard output (the value-laden produce of the program) goes. The documentation is at https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html

Comment: @joarleymoraes Thanks so much. This was, in fact, making me crazy.

Answer (score 3):

nohup program &> program.out &

or

nohup program &> program.out if you don't want to run the job in the background. I use this when I'm running multiple jobs at once and I want to limit it.

Comment: does this also re-direct stderr? I want to direct everything, whether it is an error or output to a single source.

Comment: @ncoghlan can someone give an explanation of the command? can you explain what the hieroglyphics `2>&1` mean and why it works?

Answer (score 1):

> Can someone give an explanation of the command? can you explain what the hieroglyphics 2>&1 mean and why it works?

- The `nohup` command executes the command give while ignoring SIGHUP.
- The SIGHUP stands for "hang-up", which is typically sent to a program when you lose connection to the system (network disruption.)
- If the standard output is a terminal, it defaults to writing to `nohup.out` in the current directory.
- The `2>&1` invalidates the "connected to a terminal" part.
- The `2>` means standard error is written to `&1`, which means the same as standard output.
- Then the `> program.out` tells the shell to write the standard output to the file `program.out`.

Comment: @CharlieParker Is this the kind of detail you hoped to find?